# Divide two dictionaries of float values with zero values

Tags: python, dictionary, floating-point, division, divide-by-zero

i have a problem with division error.. I use two dictionarie and i  have to divide them by other dict.. But some values are 0.. I don't want an error but i want

My two dict:

probspam:

```
  {0: [3.75199226626618e-79], 1: [1.0384638247478166e-25], 2: [3.876104531640006e-157]}
```

probham:

```
 {0: [1.0143598477460146e-78], 1: [0.0], 2: [2.2740883119510355e-138]}
```

the wrong function:

```
def bayes (probspam, probham):
    try:
        lista={k: [probspam[k][0]/probham[k][0]] for k in probham}
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        k=0
    return lista
```

how can i tell my  system that when `probham[k]=0`, it should assign 0 to the result of the division and not give me:"ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero"?

Comment: lista={k: [probspam[k][0]/probham[k][0] if probham[k][0] != 0 else 0.0] for k in probham}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it what you are looking for?

```
def bayes (probspam, probham):
    lista={k: [probspam[k][0]/probham[k][0] if probham[k][0] !=0 else .0] for k in probham}
    return lista
```

or, if you need a 0.0 instead of [0.0] as a value

```
def bayes (probspam, probham):
    lista={k: [probspam[k][0]/probham[k][0]] if probham[k][0] !=0 else .0 for k in probham}
    return lista
```

List/dict comprehensions is powerful! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def bayes(probspam, probham):
    lista = {}
    for k in probham:
        if probham[k][0] != 0:
            lista[k] = [probspam[k][0]/probham[k][0]]
        else:
            lista[k] = [0.0]

    return lista
```